# Changing image source attribute in Vue.js + TypeScript

Tags: html, typescript, image, vue.js

So I have a simple img tag:

```
<img @error="replaceByDefaultImage" :src="urls.photos_base_url_small.jpg'"/>
```

And replaceByDefaultImage function looks like this:

```
replaceByDefaultImage(e: HTMLImageElement) {
  e.src = '/img/default.png';
}
```

Now in case the `photos_base_url_small` is missing, the `replaceByDefaultImage` fires but it doesn't change the image source. Or at least it doesn't change on the HTML itself. Although it works if I use target like `e.target.src = '/img/default.png';` but if I want to use target, I have to set any type to the event variable `e` and I prefer not to use this type. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
replaceByDefaultImage(e: Event) {
  (e.target as HTMLImageElement).src = '/img/default.png';
}
```

Found this solution. Looks fine I guess. Variable `e` is a type of event so we can't use it like image itself. We have to get the target element first.